# JSON bad request Unrecognized token

Tags: python, python-requests, youtrack

when trying to post via the [youtrack api](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/devportal/api-howto-create-issue.html#step-by-step) (adding a issue) I get a problematic error.

Here is my code:

```
`postHeaders = {
    'Accept':'application/json',
    'Authorization':'secret',
    'Content-Type':'application/json'
    
}

postData = {
    'project':{'id':'0-5'},
    'summary':'sample',
    'description':'Sample description'
}


responsePost = requests.post("https://yourcompany.youtrack.cloud/api/issues", headers=postHeaders, data=postData)
print(responsePost.content)`
```

I got this error:

`b'{"error":"bad_request","error_description":"Unrecognized token \'project\': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token \'null\', \'true\' or \'false\')\\n at [Source: (org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream); line: 1, column: 9]"}'`

Can You guys help.

I tried formatting in various ways JSON format I changed ' to ' but nothing would work. the result is to add a issue to the project with id 0-5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this dumping to json will support?

```
import json

postData = {
    'project': {'id': '0-5'},
    'summary': 'sample',
    'description': 'Sample description'
}

# Convert the dictionary to a JSON string
postData_json = json.dumps(postData)

print(postData_json)
```